# wix - searching a database

Tags: javascript, velo

I am a 14-year-old new to coding, so please be patient.  I am learning as quick as I can.
*

The website is a wix website.

I need a Search that takes a text input element and then filters multiple columns of a Wix dataset.

---

[EDIT:

I already have a search that I set up, but the search results are not very accurate because when a user types in a multiple word phrase (example: "clinical study" the search looks for all of the words in the same order and in the same column.

I would like it to search each row of data for both the words “clinical” AND “study”.

For a positive result, the words “clinical” AND “study” must appear in the same row -- they could be in different columns but would have to be on the same row.

**

The code looks like this.

```js
      import wixData from 'wix-data';


    export function SearchBox_keyPress(event, $w) {

        $w("#dataset1").setFilter(wixData.filter()
        )


    const filterValue = $w("#SearchBox").value
    const byTitle = wixData.filter().contains("title", filterValue)
    const byTag1 = wixData.filter().contains("tag1", filterValue)
    const byTag2 = wixData.filter().contains("tag2", filterValue)
    $w("#dataset1").setFilter(byTitle.or(byTag1.or(byTag2)))

    }
```

**

I am a volunteer helping with the data management of a COVID-19 research library.   It is put together by doctors who don’t know anything about coding so I am helping with that.  You can see what I’ve done so far here: https://www.pandemicity.org/epidemiological-research

I have had some help from forums but if anyone has better ideas of how I can get questions answered or pointed in the right direction, I would appreciate it.
Are there better forums or pages? Or a reference book?  I just need a bit of coaching as I work these things out.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Provide minimal samples of your code that can reproduce the current behavior. Also, please elaborate on "but it does not work the way I need," what does the current implementation do?

Comment: @junvar I have made some edits to the post. Please ask if you have anymore questions.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about wix dev environment but give a try to google with "wix search database", I'm sure it will guide you

Here are some useful links :
[How to create a search for your database](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/corvid-tips-and-updates/how-to-create-a-search-for-your-database)
[Adding Search to your Wix Website (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiKcx2nlrkw)

[Documentation of Wix's Corvid API](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/)
 ├─[Section about database queries](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.WixDataQuery.html)
 └─[Section about filters](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.WixDataFilter.html)

Start with a simple query and then scale up step by step,

Hope it helps and nice initiative !